# How can I Git clone a specific release?

Tags: git, github

So that's it; I finished the very first version of my application.

I committed the final state of the first version:

```
git commit -m "some final tweaks"
```

And created the versioning tag:

```
git tag v1.0.0
```

And `push`ed everything remotely.

Now, I am in the process of starting developing the second version of the application with some improvements I already have in mind.

Is it possible, later, when I'd made these improvements and `commit` and create a new `tag` (**v2.0.0**), to Git clone a specific state of Git providing a tag?

If the last version is **v2.0.0**, can I still clone the version **1.0.x**?

Something like `git clone git@github.com:mygitname/theproject.git#1.0.2` for instance?

Answer (score 90):

You can do this with the `--branch` flag, which will also accept a tag.

```
git clone  git@github.com:mygitname/theproject.git --branch 1.0.2
```

In most cases, you will just want to checkout the tag as described in [Exprator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241502/how-can-i-git-clone-a-specific-release/45241553#45241553) (now deleted).

Comment: it works better like this: `$ git clone  git@github.com:mygitname/theproject.git --branch v1.0.2`

Comment: @MaxMuster That looks the same just with a different tag name.

Comment: @vdegenne Branch and tag names are not required to start with a "v".

Answer (score 27):

With Git you usually don't clone a particular version; you `clone` the entire repository - making a local copy of the every version - and then `checkout` a specific version.

By default when you clone, a specific version (usually `master`) is checked out. You can change which version is checked out with the `-b` option (or, of course, you can just check out the desired version after the clone completes).

But there are scenarios where that's not practically useful advice, such as if you're using `npm` to fetch something from Git (so you don't directly issue a `clone` command).  In the case of `npm`, you can add a commit identifier (branch, tag, commit SHA, etc.) to the end of the URL as a hash fragment.  (AFAIK, that *only* works with `npm` though; it doesn't work with `git clone` the way you asked about.)

For completeness's sake, if you *really* wanted to clone just a particular version (copying only that version from the remote to your local machine), you could do something like

```
git clone --depth 1 -b branch_name <url>
```

(where `branch_name` is the name of either a branch or a tag).

Comment: Where should I mention the repo URL in the command you have mentioned above? Thanks!

Comment: The `git clone` syntax puts all options before the URL (which may then be followed by a path to a local directory in which to clone).  So for the situation described here, the URL would go last.