# How can I clone a specific release in Git?

Tags: git, github, release

Well, I saw someone talking about cloning a Git release, but I didn't understand it, and I followed the tutorial given by them.

*[How can I Git clone a specific release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241502/how-to-git-clone-a-specific-release)*

This is the tutorial command given by them.

```
git clone  git@github.com:mygitname/theproject.git --branch 1.0.2
```

Here are some commands that I have tried.

```
git clone  git@github.com:discordjs/discord.js --branch 13.2.0

Cloning into 'discord.js'...
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
```

```
git clone https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.2.0

Cloning into '13.2.0'...
fatal: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.2.0/info/refs not valid: could not determine hash algorithm; is this a git repository?
```

```
git clone discordjs/discord.js --branch 13.2.0

fatal: repository 'discordjs/discord.js' does not exist
```

But nothing really worked. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the Git remote URL that you're trying with.

Try with the below and it would clone the particular release

```
git clone https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js.git --branch 13.2.0
```

The reasons why the ones you are trying with are not working:

```
// The remote URL is an SSH URL and you probably don't have the SSH software installed
git clone git@github.com:discordjs/discord.js --branch 13.2.0

// Not valid Git remote URLs
git clone https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/13.2.0
git clone discordjs/discord.js --branch 13.2.0
```